# ie7 bug: Floats get pushed down

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7

If you go to http://www.wilwaldon.com/learning/inner4a.html with IE7 you will see the middle 2 columns being pushed to the bottom of the page. I've tried using display:inline on both columns but to no avail.

Any help is greatly appreciated, and thanks in advance!

Comment: What browser displays your page the way you desire?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because that header with class=h1full2 has width 1000 px and doesn't fit. Make your header width = 700px and put it into div with id=contentleft.

Also remove empty paragraph below header.

Comment: THANK YOU! I JUST caught this with firebug right when you posted haha.

Thanks again!